# sed command to change value in .spec file

Tags: json, linux, sed, jq

How to change a value in .spec file using sed? Want to change the `$nmatch` value of build to someother value say `"build1.1"`.

```
{
"files": [
  {
    "aql": {
    "items.find": {
    "repo": {"$eq":"app-java-repo"},
    "path": "archives/test/app",
    "type": "folder",
    "$or": [
          {
            "$and": [
              {
                "name": {"$nmatch" : "*build*"} //change value using sed
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
}
```

Tried below command but not working

```
sed -i -e '/name:/{s/\($nmatch\).*/\1: "'"build1.1"'" /}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document format is json, so you should use jq for editing:

```
jq '.files[0].aql."items.find"."$or"[0]."$and"[0].name."$nmatch"="build1.1"' spec
```

With *sed*, you can't reliably access the correct name node. Your code doesn't work because you didn't include the quotes around `name` in your search pattern. Using sed would be ok if you have a unique identifier for *build*. Example:

```
sed -i 's/BUILD_NUMBER/build1.1/g' spec
```

Comment: I guess I will go with jq

Answer (score 0):

A more "indirect" way is to simply set everything with `$nmatch`:

```
jq '(.. | select(has("$nmatch"))? ) = "build1.1"' input.json
```

Comment: How to save it out in the file?

Comment: add `> output.json` to the command line